# How to Compare Fields in same table defined by WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, compare, temp, database-table

I am trying to compare product_models in a product table between 2 different manufacturers.  I found the same product has 2 different product_model numbers. Similar but still different. For example CNELD-1004 from Manufacturers 1 (ELD) is the same product as 1004 from Manufacturers 2 (MC).  I am trying to show the products from Manufacturers 2 where it is NOT like the same product_model from Manufacturers 1

Without using php, is there a way to do this mysql?

```
select products_model  AS MCProducts from products where manufacturers_id = 2; 

select products_model  AS ELDProducts from products where manufacturers_id = 1; 

Select  MCProducts from products WHERE MCProducts  not LIKE  "%ELDProducts%"
```

Answer (score 0):

> select products_model, CASE
>
> ```
>   WHEN manufacturers_id = 2 THEN 'MCProducts' 
>   WHEN manufacturers_id = 2 THEN 'ELDProducts'
>   END 
> from products where WHERE MCProducts  not LIKE  "%ELDProducts%"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will also work.

```
select products_model  AS MCProducts from products where manufacturers_id = 2 and     products_model not in (select products_model  from products where manufacturers_id = 1);
```